# Apple maps and overlays

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-maps

So, I'm building a app that will use MKMapView. We want to place our own layers on it. Some of which would be satellite images. These satellite images would be between 1 to 5 meter resolution which is quite clear.

Our customer will load the application with some mkpolygon layers drawn. The user will then select a satellite image which will be added as a raster layer (would be limited to a bounding box). If there is no issue with the satellite image, then we will trim the raster image to cover just a mkpolygon boundary (which we then do some image analysis for our customer).

So our satellite images are not meant to replace apple's maps, we have no intention to do that and do not want to. Our satellite images are placed on the map temporally.

I am wondering if apple will have an issue with us placing these raster satellite images as overlays over their maps? Could they see it as we are replacing their map images with your satellite images? Or can we place what ever we want over their maps (including obscuring their maps completely)?